# Elastic must match multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to fetch documents that must contains given *idfield* & *namefield* values, & must apply a date range filter with *datefield* with sorting

**Inputs:**

*idfield:* Multiple values,
*namefield:* Same value,
*datefield:* Same date range,

**Actual format:**

```
datefield idfield namefield msgfield
```

**Actual statements:**

```
2020-01-01 10:20:10 304 xyz msg1
2020-01-01 10:20:10 102 xyz msg2
2020-01-01 10:20:10 101 pqr msg3
......
2020-01-01 10:21:10 304 xyz msg4
2020-01-01 10:21:10 102 xyz msg5
......
```

The current query is given below

**Query:**

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 2000,
  "sort": [
    {
      "datefield": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "idfield.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ], 
   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "idfield": "304"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "namefield": "xyz"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "datefield": {
                    "gte":"2020-01-01T10:20:10",
                    "lte":"2020-01-01T10:30:20"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          } 
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "idfield": "102"
                }
              },
              {
                "match": {
                  "namefield": "xyz"
                }
              },
              {
                "range": {
                  "datefield": {
                    "gte":"2020-01-01T10:20:10",
                    "lte":"2020-01-01T10:30:20"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

In short, *(idfield AND namefield AND datefield range) OR (idfield AND namefield AND datefield range) OR* etc.

Ex, *(304 AND xyz AND (2020-01-01 10:20:10 >=, <= 2020-01-01 10:30:20)) OR (102 AND xyz AND (2020-01-01 10:20:10 >=, <= 2020-01-01 10:30:20)) OR* etc..

How to minimize/improve this query

Answer (score 1):

You can use [terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html#query-dsl-terms-query) query as it returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided field. Below query will work same as your current query.

```json
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "datefield": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    },
    {
      "idfield.keyword": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "terms": {
            "idfield": [
              "304",
              "102"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "terms": {
            "namefield": [
              "xyz"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "datefield": {
              "gte": "2020-01-01T10:20:10",
              "lte": "2020-01-01T10:30:20"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How to know the use case to use '.keyword' if the field has special characters like '-' or numerics saying to use '.keyword'

Comment: @nay If you want to do the exact match or aggregation then you can go for .keyword field which is not analayzed. So value will be same as your original field. But if you want to do free text search where you want to support lowercase etc. then you can go for text type of field. You can raise seperate question with all details.